# find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2 x^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2 x^n$

What I tried doing is:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2 x^n$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1) x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n x^n$

= $x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1) x^{n-2}+x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n x^{n-1} =x^2(\frac{1}{1-x})'' + x(\frac{1}{1-x})'$

But anyway I continute gets me a wrong answer so I wonder if there's some mistake here?

The answer should be $ -\frac{x(x+1)}{(x-1)^3} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is mostly correct. Your lower bounds for the summation are wrong. But that is irrelevant when it comes to your argument simplification which you must not have done correctly because you will get the right answer if you continue down the path you are currently going on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote $f(x) = \sum n^2 x^n = x \sum n^2 x^{n-1} = xg(x)$.

$\int g(x)dx = \sum nx^n = x \sum nx^{n-1} = xh(x)$

$\int h(x)dx = \sum x^n$